# Generic method for updating entity with transactions

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a GAE model with several methods that update entities with transactions.  Something like this:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):

    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def update_foo(ekey):
        entity = ekey.get()
        entity.foo = "x"
        entity.put()

    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def update_bar(ekey):
        entity = ekey.get()
        entity.bar = "y"
        entity.put()
```

To clean up my code, I was thinking, I could centralize the code that does updates with transactions.  Something like this:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):

    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def update_tx(ekey, **kwargs):
        entity = ekey.get()
        for prop, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(entity, prop, value)
        enitty.put()

    def update_foo(self):
        self.update_tx(self.key, foo="x")

    def update_bar(self):
        self.update_tx(self.key, bar="y")
```

Is this a reasonable idea, or are there dangers in this approach that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reasonable. It really depends on your use case.

I actually had something similar in place, but more and more I have to special case my `update_tx()` for each entity type to the point that only 1 or 2 of my ~10 models still use it, because there is almost always other logic that needs to be executed.

- If I update a user's account state from 'deactivated' to 'activated' I need to perform a few queries to see if they completed all the mandatory onboarding steps.
- If a user updates their email I have to send a new verification link to that new email before it can change
- Certain fields are only editable if the entity is in a certain state
- If a user submit's a new start date and end date, I need to save the old start date and end date in new object for historical purposes
- etc

That logic could happen outside of this function, but I often want that to happen in the same transaction.

That aside, one thing it doesn't seem to handle is needing to update a batch of entities in a single transaction, so your pseudo code would need to look more like this if that's important to you:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):

    def update_properties(self, **kwargs):
        for prop, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, prop, value)

    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional(xg=True)
    def update_txs(keys, updates):
        # keys is an array of ndb.Key()s, 
        # updates is an array of the same size, containing **kwargs for each key
        entities = ndb.get_multi(keys)
        for index, entity in enumerate(entities):
            entity.update_properties(**updates[index])
        ndb.put_multi(entities)

    @classmethod
    def update_tx(cls, ekey, **kwargs):
        cls.update_txs([ekey], [kwargs])

    def update_foo(self):
        self.update_tx(self.key, foo="x")

    def update_bar(self):
        self.update_tx(self.key, bar="y")
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the insights.  I'm struggling to figure out what needs to be in the transaction and what can be before the transaction.  For example, tt seems that validating form data could be done before the transaction, but other operations are less clear.

Comment: Sure thing. You will always have some validation in the model, in fact ndb lets you set validator functions on properties. I'm actually in the middle of refactoring how I do validation because lots of rules had to be able to be overridden for admins / customer service reps making changes (i.e. a user can only set a datetime to be in the future, but admins needed to be able to back-date things). The route I'm currently going is putting data-integrity validation in the model / transaction, and validation based on permissions outside of the model (along with timestamp->datetime checks).